# Downloading Images from Firebase Storage Faster

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, firebase-storage, android-glide

The current architecture structure that I have for my Firebase storage is as follow:

> Photos_folder/
>   -->users ID 01 **-->** profile_picture_folder/**-->** image/jpeg (URI)
>   -->users ID 02
>   -->users ID 03
>   --> ect...

In my adapter, I have an `onBindViewHolder` method where I'm passing my `URI` and retrieving the uri image through Firebase Storage network:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final CommentViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Uri imageUri = Uri.parse(list.get(position).getImageUri());

    photosStorageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
    photosStorageReference.child(Constant.PHOTOS_FIREBASE).child(userId)
            .child(Constant.USER_PROFILE_PICTURE_FOLDER).child(imageUri.getLastPathSegment())
            .getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
            SimpleTarget target = new SimpleTarget<Bitmap> (200, 200) {
                @Override
                public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Bitmap bitmap, @Nullable Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                }
            };
            GlideApp.with(context).asBitmap().load(uri).diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.DATA).apply(
                    RequestOptions.circleCropTransform()).into(target);
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

**PROBLEM:**
Everything is working fine, however, `onSuccess` method is doing the work in main thread and it's synchronous so the app is waiting between each image retrieval.

**Is there anyway of achieving images retrieval from Firebase faster?**

Maybe like establishing the connection to Firebase at a higher reference level, **for example:**
gs://appname-b4532.appspot.com/Photos/

After the connection is open, going over user ids and retrieving their respective image while going over sub path?

userId01/Profile_picture_folder/image_01
userId02/Profile_picture_folder/image_02
userId03/Profile_picture_folder/image_03
..ect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of your work with Firebase here is actually synchronous, nor is it blocking the main thread.  None of the Firebase SDKs provide blocking methods.  Whenever you have a Task object, that work is being done on another thread.

Also, Glide works fully asynchronously - it does not block the thread that you used to invoke it.

Any delays you're seeing are just inherent in the system.

Comment: Doug, can you please share documentation on Firebase work being asynchronous? Also, I believe that the connection is being opened and closed here every time one image is retrieved, isn't that going to consume more time? Also, I tried another published Google Play app in the same device, and images retrieval was much faster. I understand that there are other variants but the functionality is almost similar as to what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: All Tasks are async.  https://developers.google.com/android/guides/tasks. All Firebase APIs are async: https://medium.com/google-developers/why-are-firebase-apis-asynchronous-callbacks-promises-tasks-e037a6654a93